# Resources.Load returning null in Editor scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to implement a simple Resources.Load call in an editor script i'm making, but it continues to return null despite the numerous different approaches I've tried.

**Purpose**

- User adds .jpg's to a folder in the project, in this case Assets/Resources/360Photos

  - Postprocess script detects this file, applies cubemap texture import settings to it
  - Script will then create a skybox/cubemap material and apply the texture to the material

The roadblock I have hit is getting the texture object after it has been post processed as a cubemap, and how it would then be applied to the _Tex property of a Skybox/Cubemap shaded material, as I can't seem to even load the resource associated with the texture I import and process to a cubemap.

Is it possible to use Resources.Load in Unity Editor Scripting (AssetPostProcessor in particular) or am I trying to perform functionality that is only available at runtime?

If somebody could look over my code, and view the Unity screenshot I have provided, that would be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Postprocess360Photo : AssetPostprocessor {

void OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)
{
    string lowerCaseAssetPath = assetPath.ToLower ();
    bool isIn360PhotoDirectory = lowerCaseAssetPath.IndexOf ("360photos") != -1;

    if (isIn360PhotoDirectory) 
    {
        TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Default;
        textureImporter.textureShape = TextureImporterShape.TextureCube;
        textureImporter.generateCubemap = TextureImporterGenerateCubemap.Cylindrical;
        textureImporter.sRGBTexture = true;
        textureImporter.alphaSource = TextureImporterAlphaSource.FromInput;
        textureImporter.alphaIsTransparency = true;
        textureImporter.npotScale = TextureImporterNPOTScale.ToSmaller;
        textureImporter.isReadable = true;
        textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = false;
        textureImporter.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        textureImporter.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
    }

    AssetDatabase.ImportAsset (assetPath);
    CreateMaterial ();
}

void CreateMaterial ()
{
    Cubemap cubemap = (Cubemap)Resources.Load ("360Photos/FrontDriveway");
    Debug.Log (cubemap);
}
}
```

Please see image for hierarchy structure and console verification of a null return value:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uqBF.jpg

Using Unity 5.5.0f3 if that helps.

Comment: could you try `Cubemap cubemap = Resources.Load("360Photos/FrontDriveway") as Cubemap ;` And check in the inspector that the "Texture Type" of your resource is "Cubemap"

Comment: Hi @Chong, thank you for your response.

I tried the code as you said, and still no result. There is no longer a type "Cubemap" in the inspector Texture Type anymore, I think they changed that with Unity 5.5, and as such the type is Default, with a Texture Shape of Cube.

Please see image link if desired:-

http://imgur.com/a/A4aYj

Comment: What is the format/extension of the FrontDriveway file? Also, is this the exact code you are using in your project right now?

Comment: Hi @Programmer, yes this is the exact code being used right now. The extension is a .jpg, however trying with both .jpg and without the extension produce identical results. For the sake of cleanliness I simply left it out in the current copy of the script.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps because it is a cubemap within Unity only, not so much within the file structure, that I might not be able to perform Resources.Load on a cubemap?

Comment: @AndrewMMG but looks like the doc said "Cubemap" should be there, um, I feel it is pretty weird. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cubemap.html

Comment: @Chong it definitely used to be before 5.5, but now it has the Texture shape property of the Texture type Default, which contains 2D or Cube shape. The documentation, despite saying "Version 5.5" at the top, might be inaccurate.

Unless you are using Unity Editor V5.5 and it is allowing you to select Cubemap as a Texture Type?

I could, of course, revert to an older version of Unity Editor, which I might do tomorrow, it's just that I was curious as to finding a solution here in 5.5 is all.

Comment: @AndrewMMG that's really interesting, how they make the official doc different from actual Editor. That's probably why our project is using 5.4 and we don't want to take a risk updating. Almost all of our project is in 2d so I am afraid I can't help more with the Cubemap thing. Good luck and hope you can find a way out~

Comment: @Chong thank you for the assistance. I'll let you know if I find a working solution in 5.5 or 5.4

Answer (score 0):

> The extension is a .jpg, however trying with both .jpg and without the
>   extension produce identical results.

That's the problem

*.Jpg* `!=` *.cubemap*.

To get a cubemap go to *Assets*->*Create*->*Legacy*->*Cubemap*.

If you name it *FrontDriveway* and place it at *Resources/360Photos*, that should work.

**EDIT**:

There is an exception to what I said above. If you change the `TextureImporter` 's `generateCubemap` and `textureShape` properties then you can import the image as a `Cubemap`.

It looks like there is a bug with Unity's `Resources.Load` function. You can't call `Resources.Load` from the `OnPostprocessTexture` function. Maybe this is a `Thread` issue? I don't know.

After experimenting for a long time, I found a work around. After processing the image, you need to implement [`EditorApplication.update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-update.html) callback function and use that to call your  `Resources.Load` code.

```
public class Postprocess360Photo : AssetPostprocessor
{
    EditorApplication.CallbackFunction doneEvent;
    string path;

    void OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        string lowerCaseAssetPath = assetPath.ToLower();
        bool isIn360PhotoDirectory = lowerCaseAssetPath.IndexOf("360photos") != -1;

        if (isIn360PhotoDirectory)
        {
            TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
            textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Default;
            textureImporter.textureShape = TextureImporterShape.TextureCube;
            textureImporter.generateCubemap = TextureImporterGenerateCubemap.Cylindrical;
            textureImporter.sRGBTexture = true;
            textureImporter.alphaSource = TextureImporterAlphaSource.FromInput;
            textureImporter.alphaIsTransparency = true;
            textureImporter.npotScale = TextureImporterNPOTScale.ToSmaller;
            textureImporter.isReadable = true;
            textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = false;
            textureImporter.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
            textureImporter.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
        }

        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(assetPath);
        path = assetPath;

        doneEvent = null;
        doneEvent = new EditorApplication.CallbackFunction(afterProcessing);

        //Add doneEvent function to call back!
        EditorApplication.update = (EditorApplication.CallbackFunction)Delegate.Combine(EditorApplication.update, doneEvent);
    }

    private void afterProcessing()
    {
        //Remove doneEvent function from call back!
        EditorApplication.update = (EditorApplication.CallbackFunction)Delegate.Remove(EditorApplication.update, doneEvent);

        Material mat = CreateMaterial(path);

        //Change skybox?
        RenderSettings.skybox = mat;
    }


    Material CreateMaterial(string filePath)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        fileName = fileName + ".mat";

        /*
        assetPath/path returns as "Assets/Resources/360Photos/FrontDriveway.jpg"
        Remove the "Assets/Resources/"
         */
        filePath = filePath.Replace("Assets/Resources/", "");

        //Remove the extension name (.jpg)
        filePath = filePath.Substring(0, filePath.LastIndexOf("."));

        // Cubemap cubemap = (Cubemap)Resources.Load("360Photos/FrontDriveway");
        Cubemap cubemap = (Cubemap)Resources.Load(filePath);
        Debug.Log(cubemap);

        Material skyBoxMat = new Material(Shader.Find("Skybox/Cubemap"));
        skyBoxMat.SetTexture("_Tex", cubemap);

        //Optional, saves the material to Assets/Resources/360Photos/" + fileName
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(skyBoxMat, "Assets/Resources/360Photos/" + fileName);
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();

        return skyBoxMat;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is true, however I realise I should have given context as to the purpose of the script. I will edit my description as whilst this makes a cubemap, it wont serve the purpose I am after.

Comment: Hi @Programmer, please see the Purpose section I added to my question, as this will provide some context as to why I am trying to access the cubemap as a cubemap texture in the import settings, not by a 6 sided cubemap legacy file.

If you are able to provide any insight, I appreciate your effort in assisting me. Thank you.

Comment: You lost me. My answer says that you can't cast jpg to Cubemap (`(Cubemap)Resources.Load("...")`).  You need this for skybox? To create a material for a skybox?

Comment: The reason that I am converting the imported texture to a cubemap is to put it on the texture property of the "Skybox/Cubemap" shader, with the material being applied to a Camera's "Skybox" component. That is why I can not use a Legacy/Cubemap asset, because I do not have 6 faces, I just have the Unity Texture Importer cubemap cylindrical settings.

Do you know of a way in the Unity Assetpostprocessor or other UnityEditor method of applying a cubemap asset to a material? As that is ultimately what I am trying to achieve. The Resources.Load approach I attempted may be the incorrect method.

Comment: say @Programmer buddy .. do you happen to use the (crappy) unity forum/answers site?  (there's no PM on SO)  cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow Nope. Happy new year. I will create one today when I get time and will provide link to it.

Comment: hi @Programmer no worries you can easily find me there users/16424/fattie.html maybe drop me a PM.  Happy NY

Comment: hi @Programmer, thank you very much. sorry for the late reply i went on holidays, but yesterday got back in the office and quickly made up a scriptable wizard to perform the functionality. combining it in the postprocess is also desirable, however, and so thank you for your assistance!

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem, you can accept it as answer.